# Python Object Oriented Programming

Tags: python, variables

Am trying to understand object oriented programming with python. Am new to programming.
I have this class that is giving me an error I don't understand and I will be glad if anyone can throw more light on this for me:

```
class TimeIt(object):

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def test_one(self):
        print 'executed'

    def test_two(self, word):
        self.word = word
        i = getattr(self, 'test_one')
        for i in xrange(12):
            sleep(1)
            print 'hello, %s and %s:' % (self.word, self.name),
            i()

j = TimeIt('john')  
j.test_two('mike')
```

If I run this class I get `'int' object is not callable" TypeError`

However, if I precede the `i` with `self` (`self.i`), it works.

```
class TimeIt(object):

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def test_one(self):
        print 'executed'

    def test_two(self, word):
        self.word = word
        self.i = getattr(self, 'test_one')
        for i in xrange(12):
            sleep(1)
            print 'hello, %s and %s:' % (self.word, self.name),
            self.i()
```

My question is, doesn't `i = getattr(self, 'test_one')` assign the test_one function to `i`?
How come `i()` doesn't work?
Why does `self.i()` work?
Why is `i` an `int` (hence the `'int' object is not callable TypeError`)?
That's a lot of questions. Thanks in advance

Comment: i think i just realised it. I shouldn't have used 'i' since am using it to iterate over xrange(). pheeew

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're overwriting `i` within loop. When you're "preceding" `i` with `self`, you're creating different variable, which is not overwritten.

Answer (score 2):

@SilentGhost is right on the money with his answer.

To illustrate, try chaning the test_two method to this:

```
def test_two(self, word):
    self.word = word
    i = getattr(self, 'test_one')
    for some_other_variable_besides_i in xrange(12):
        sleep(1)
        print 'hello, %s and %s:' % (self.word, self.name),
        i()
```

Your code overwrite the variable i (set as a method) within the for loop (see comments)

```
def test_two(self, word):
    self.word = word
    i = getattr(self, 'test_one')
    # i is now pointing to the method self.test_one
    for i in xrange(12):
        # now i is an int based on it being the variable name chosen for the loop on xrange
        sleep(1)
        print 'hello, %s and %s:' % (self.word, self.name),
        i()
```

In addition, you certainly don't need to assign the test_one method to a variable like `i`.  Instead, you can just call the method replacing

```
i()
```

with

```
self.test_one()
```